# Show that a compact operator has closed image in $\ell^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that we have a sequence $(a_k)_k$ s.t. $a_k \to 0$(not necessarily in $\ell^p(1 \le p < \infty)$). Then we can define a bounded linear operator $T : \ell^p \to \ell^p, (x_k)_k \mapsto (a_k x_k)_k$, I want to show that $T(B_1)$ is a closed set, where $B_1$ is the closed unit ball in $\ell^p$.

Some observations are the following :

1. $T$ is compact, because we can approximate it by finite rank operator, just taking the first n terms of $(a_k)_k$, let the other terms be zero.
2. If $p > 1$, then I can use some machinery to show $T(B_1)$ is closed, becasue in this case $\ell^p$ is reflexive, so I can use weak compactness of the unit ball to find the desired preimage.

My question is, how can I prove this for $p = 1$ ? Or probably this is not true, then I'd like to see a conterexample. And I was stuck to find a suitable preimage, if we assume that $T\vec{x}_k \to \vec{y}$, one of the candidate should be $(y_k/a_k)_k$, but I can't even show this is an element in $\ell^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that $T$ maps $\ell^{p}$ into itself, we need boundedness of $(a_k)$. But $a_k \to 0$ is not necessary for showing that $T(B_1)$ is closed.

Suppose $\sum_k |x_k^{(n)}| \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $T(x^{(n)})=(a_k x_k^{n})\to (y_k)$ in $\ell^{1}$.  Let $x_k=\frac {y_k}{a_k}$ if $a_k \neq 0$ and $x_k=0$ if $a_k=0$. Then $a_kx_k=y_k$ for all $k$. If we show that $\sum|x_k| \leq 1$ we are done since $(y_k)=T(x_k)$. By Fatou's Lemma we have $\sum_{a_k \neq 0} |\frac {y_k}{a_k}| \leq \lim \inf \sum_{a_k \neq 0} |\frac {a_kx_k^{n}}{a_k}|\leq \lim \inf \sum | x_k^{n}| \leq 1$. Thus, $\sum |x_k| \leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you. So you view $l^p$ as a measure space with counting measure, and pointwise covergence becomes convergence at each coordinate, right ? But I still don't see where you used $a_k \to 0$.

Comment: $a_k \to 0$ is not necessary. @gaga

Answer (score 1):

Fix $1\le p<\infty.$ Let $K_n$ denote the set of $x\in \ell^p$ such that $$f_n(x):=\sum_{k=1,a_k\neq 0}^n {|x_k|^p\over |a_k|^p}\le 1$$ and $x_k=0$ if $a_k=0,$ for $k=1,2\ldots,n.$ The set $K_n$ is closed as the function $f_n$ is continuous on $\ell^p.$ We have $$T(B_1)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n$$ Therefore the set $T(B_1)$ is closed.

For $p=\infty $ the set $K_n$  is defined is the collection of $x\in \ell^\infty$ such that $|a_n|^{-1}|x_n|\le 1$ if $a_n\neq 0$. Then $T(B_1)=\bigcap K_n.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  have you used the condtion $a_k \to 0$ ??

Comment: No, I haven't used that property

Comment: I see, thanks. Could you explain how you came up with the idea of doing this ? This seems a little technical for me.

Comment: If $a_n\neq 0$ for every $n$, then  $T(B_1)$ is equal to the collection of sequences such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  {|x_n|^p\over |a_n|^p}\le 1$$